# About the series $\sum 3^n\sin\big( \frac 1{4^n} x\big)$ on $(a,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

The series $\sum 3^n\sin\big( \frac 1{4^n} x\big)$ converges absolutely and uniformly on $(a,\infty)$ where $a\gt 0$.

The utmost I can think of is to prove the uniform convergence on bounded intervals $(a,b]$ by using $|\sin x|\le |x|$ and the $M_n$ test for series.

I don't know how to pass on to unbounded interval. Also it's easy to see the (limit)sum function $s(x)$ satisfy $|s(x)|\le 3x$ though I couldn't get $s(x)$ explicitly.

Please help me with this problem. Thanks for your suggestion and time.

Answer (score 2):

Absolute convergence isn't a problem to prove. Uniform convergence does not hold for an unbounded interval. If it would, there would be a $K\ge 1$ such that

$$\lvert s(x)-\sum_{n=1}^k 3^n\sin\left(\frac{x}{4^n}\right)\rvert < 1, \forall x, \forall k \ge K.$$

Select any $m\ge K$. Because the above inequality holds for both $k=m$ and $k=m+1$, we have

$$\lvert s(x)-\sum_{n=1}^m 3^n\sin\left(\frac{x}{4^n}\right)\rvert < 1, \forall x$$

and

$$\lvert s(x)-\sum_{n=1}^{m+1} 3^n\sin\left(\frac{x}{4^n}\right)\rvert = \lvert s(x)-\sum_{n=1}^{m} 3^n\sin\left(\frac{x}{4^n}\right) - 3^{m+1}\sin\left(\frac{x}{4^{m+1}}\right)\rvert < 1, \forall x.$$

If we abbreviate $s(x)-\sum_{n=1}^m 3^n\sin\left(\frac{x}{4^n}\right)$ as $d_m(x)$, this means

$$|d_m(x)| < 1\text{ and } |d_m(x) - 3^{m+1}\sin\left(\frac{x}{4^{m+1}}\right)| < 1,$$

so by the triangle inequality we get 
$$ \lvert 3^{m+1}\sin\left(\frac{x}{4^{m+1}}\right)\rvert < 2, \forall x, \forall m \ge K.$$

That's not true for $m=K, x=4^{m+1}\frac{\pi}2$, for example.

What makes me a bit suspicious is that there may be some mistake from transcribing the orignal problem to here is the part of $a$ in the problem statement. A statement like 
"uniformly convergent on $(a,\infty)$ for all $a>0$" usually signifies that $x=0$ is a problem case for the summation, usually a singularity. That's not the case here, the summation is totally well behaving around $x=0$.

Was the original problem talking about

$$\sum_{n=1}^k 3^n\sin\left(\frac{1}{4^nx}\right)$$

or something similar?

Comment: Thanks for your response, sir. I absolutely agree with you on the absurd pressence of $a$ as lower bound.As to the originality or truthfulness of the question being asked, I am very sorry not to be able to confirm it since I received it from a freind during group discussion who himself was skeptical about it.

Comment: By the way, can you please clarify ,why $|3^nsin\big(\frac x{4^n}\big)| \lt 2,\forall x,\forall n\gt K$ follows from first equality? Have you assumed $s(x)=0$?

Comment: @Kishore I added that explanation in the solution. It's basically the idea that if a series converges, the summands need to converge to 0 (a necessary but not sufficient condition for convergence). This is just the proof for that spelled out for an $\epsilon=1$.

Comment: @Ingix..That was very helpful. Thanks for the explanation.